# Validating random variable generation from inverse transform sampling

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

I'm building a simulator and I have to implement some probability distributions. What is the best (formal) way of validating this implementation? I took a look at KS-tests but it seems to me they are too easy to pass when setting $\alpha = 5\%$, for instance. Actually, it seems counterintuitive that decreasing $\alpha$ makes the test easier to pass, because, in this case, the objective is to actually accept the null hypothesis, not reject it. Also, chi-squared tests don't seem like the right choice because the distributions are continuous. Perhaps I'm missing something in my research, but is there a standard way to validate a (continuous) probability distribution implementation?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201116/best-way-to-check-implementation-of-density-distribution-function-and-random-ge/272256#272256 ?

Comment: @Xi'an That's about the best possible solution--consider reposting it as an actual answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than looking for a single (and therefore incomplete or insufficient) statistical test for one specific distribution $F$, one could call the whole collection of (Uniform) randomness tests constructed by the late Georges Marsaglia that he entitled [DieHard](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RDieHarder/vignettes/RDieHarder.pdf). They cover several dozens of assessment of randomness. For instance, the corresponding (enlarged) R package is RDieHarder. The first step is to transform the simulated sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ by the targetted cdf $F(\cdot)$, assuming it is continuous, since the transformed random variable $F(X_i)$ is $\mathcal U(0,1)$.