# How to empirically check a PDF

Tags: probability, inference, random-variable, monte-carlo, goodness-of-fit

**Intro**

Let $Y$ be a random variable whose PDF is $p_Y(\cdot)$. Let's say that $Y$ is a function $g(\cdot)$ of another random variable $X$ whose PDF $p_X(\cdot)$ is given. Then, you do your calculation and you end up with the analytic expression of the PDF $p_Y(\cdot)$.

My general question is: how do verify that your result for $p_Y(\cdot)$ is correct?

I think that there are plenty of method that answers my question. First of all there are two necessary conditions to be verified:

1. for all $y$ must be $p_Y\geq 0$;
2. it must be $\int p_Y = 1$.

If these conditions are not verified then for sure there is an error in the derivation of $p_Y$. But what about sufficient conditions that allows you to be confident in your result

**My approach**

So far my favourite method consists in the Monte Carlo method: with my lovely PC I generate a big sample $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^N$ according to $p_X(\cdot)$ and then I make a plot where I overlap the histogram of $\{y_i=g(x_i)\}_{i=1}^N$ versus the curve of the PDF $p_Y(\cdot)$
obtained analitically. Then, if  $\{y_i=g(x_i)\}_{i=1}^N$ "resembles" $p_Y(\cdot)$ I state that $p_Y(\cdot)$ is correct.
In order to be even more confident, I use to repeat the procedure for increasing values of $N$, and if the histogram seems to converge towards $p_Y(\cdot)$ then I accept the result of
$p_Y(\cdot)$.

But, despite it is very intuitive (and not 100% rigorous because it is not quantitative - everything is done by eye), there is a catch with this simple method: it works only if $Y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n=1,2$. Unfortunately, now I have to study cases where $n=3$ and $n=6$. How do you deal with that?

At a first glance I was thinking to the trivial extension where I make a proper plot for each component of $Y$, i.e. I repeat the procedure on each scalar marginal PDF. The problem is that if there is agreement within the histograms and their relative PDFs then only a necessary condition is verified (because only the marginal PDFs are verified, and not the joint PDF).

As a second method, I was thinking about something more rigorous. In particular I was thinking about some [goodness of fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit) method. Currently, I've studied only the Chi-squared and the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test in the simple scalar case (i.e. $n=1$).
Hence, I was thinking to adapt such test to my cases.

**Question**

Before falling down in the rabbit hole, I would like to have an opinion from someone that has already faced this type of problems, since I believe that are very common in the community of statisticians.
In particular, I would like to have a precise study direction:

is there a dominant validation method? I mean, is there a method that is more suitable to solve my validation problem?

Comment: While it doesn't answer your question, it's related https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201116/best-way-to-check-implementation-of-density-distribution-function-and-random-ge/272256#272256

Comment: Ooh, thank you so much Tim! I totally missed that post, I'll give it a closer look

Comment: Various problems lend themselves to different approaches.  *E.g.*, if you think the distribution is multivariate Normal, you can check random univariate linear combinations for Normality. There are myriad ways to double-check mathematical derivations.  You can check special cases that reduce to tractable calculations, *etc.* I have answered many questions here using such calculations and endeavored in most cases to check them.  I believe those answers exhibit a wide range of verification techniques. Checking the univariate and bivariate marginals through simulation likely predominates.

Comment: Thank you whuber,  I'll check your past post about this topic

Comment: A very principled way of comparing samples to distributions is Maximum Mean Discrepancy. See this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/276618/8298)

Comment: very interesting, thank you so much